# How to create a DB Model for Anonymous users?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have created a web app using Flask where you can leave a note as text. Ig goes well you leave a text and it got saved in our database. But it only happens when you are an authorized user and can't be done if you are an unauthorized (anonymous user) and if you attempt as such this error message pops up: "'AnonymousUserMixin' object has no attribute 'id'".

Here the code goes:

```
#home.py

def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        note = request.form.get('note')
    if len(note) < 1:
        flash('Note is too short!', category='error')
    else:
        new_note = Note(data=note, user_id=current_user.id)
        db.session.add(new_note)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Note added!', category='success')

return render_template("home.html", user=current_user)
```

And the DB models:

```
#models.py
class Note(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    notes = db.relationship('Note')
```

Comment: Do you mean  model classes or the part where the text is reqested after http request?

Comment: @AbdulrahmanBres here it goes I did share the code

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a `user_id` value when creating a `Note`:

```
new_note = Note(data=note, user_id=current_user.id)
```

Evidently anonymous users  don't have an `id` attribute, so you must either set `user_id=None` when creating notes for anonymous users or create a default user to represent anonymous users and user that user's `id` when creating notes.

Comment: I've tried user_id=None, it doesn't work. So apparently I need to create a default user and give it a try.